# How to write advance complex SQL Query for below data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**How to write a complex SQL Query?**

Below information is the old data of users working on different services with service status and last change date on particular Service_Area and Service_Sector.
All users are working on multiple services where some of the services are still active for a particular Service_Area and Service_Sector.

**Requirements in words:**

I require to select all columns when the Service of the user is inactive and only record on that particular Service_Area and Service_Sector of that user.

As earlier mentioned that a user can have multiple services on a Service_Area and Service_Sector combined. In case if there are more than one services on Service_Area and Service_Sector for the user, then we need to select the record that was last changed if all the services are inactive (I mean, when there is a record in between whose service status is active, then we cant select any user data from that Service_Area and Service_Sector of that user).

**Scenarios:**

***Case 1:***
When there are 5-services, all of them are inactive then, we need to select the last changed record.

***Case 2:***
When there is at least one service with active status among 5-services then, we cant select that user data from that particular Service_Area and Service_Sector of that user.

***Case 3***
When there is only one service on that Service_Area and Service_Sector of that user, it's inactive then, the record will also get selected.

**About Table:**

Location_Code, User_Id, Service_Area, Service_Sector, Service will always make a unique combination. And there may be many services on this combination Location_Code, User_Id, Service_Area, Service_Sector.

Please find the sample table below with the result table (display expected output).

**Sample Table:**

| Loc_Code | User_Id | Service_Area | Service_Sector | Service | Status | Last_Changed |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **101** | **1001** | **C** | **1** | **PAINT** | **INACTIVE** | **11/28/2020** |  |
| 101 | 1002 | A | 1 | WOOD | INACTIVE | 12/7/2020 |  |
| 101 | 1002 | A | 1 | CLEANING | ACTIVE | 11/23/2020 |  |
| 101 | 1002 | A | 1 | PEST | INACTIVE | 12/7/2020 |  |
| **101** | **1002** | **A** | **2** | **LIGHT** | **INACTIVE** | **12/7/2020** | ` |
| 101 | 1002 | B | 2 | AC | INACTIVE | 11/28/2020 |  |
| **101** | **1002** | **B** | **2** | **HEATER** | **INACTIVE** | **11/30/2020** |  |

**Result Table:**

Total 3-records are selected.

1. The first record is selected as the user was working on a single inactive service on a particular Service_Area and Service_Sector.
2. The second record is selected because Location_Code, User_Id, Service_Area, Service_Sector combination has only one service on it, which is inactive.
3. The third record selected because Location_Code, User_Id, Service_Area, Service_Sector combination list 2-inactive services, selected the service which was last changed.

| Loc_Code | User_Id | Service_Area | Service_Sector | Service | Status | Last_Changed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1001 | c | 1 | PAINT | INACTIVE | 11/28/2020 |
| 101 | 1002 | A | 2 | LIGHT | INACTIVE | 12/7/2020 |
| 101 | 1002 | B | 2 | HEATER | INACTIVE | 11/30/2020 |

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
                     !SUM(status != 'INACTIVE') OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector) only_inactive,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector ORDER BY last_changed DESC) rn
              FROM test )
              
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE only_inactive
  AND rn = 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33dd3fcfc14d82a9df3c76170fa1636b)

---

> how this query is working?

WITH is a clause which creates... think that this is a subquery.

What I do in it? I calculate 2 additional columns.  Both uses window functions - it is similar to aggregate function, but with its own grouping and ordering.

First summarises the result of checking does a column not contain specified value. For `'INACTIVE'` the checking result is FALSE which is treated as zero, for all another it is TRUE and 1 respectively. So if none `'INACTIVE'` in this group the sum is zero, and above zero if at least one another value meet. NOT inverts this result.

Second enumerates rows in a group by specified ordering.

In outer query I simply select rows which have non-zero checking result (i.e. the rows from groups which have no another statuses than 'INACTIVE'), and from these rows only the row which number is 1 (taking into account the ordering - the most recent row).

That's all.

Comment: Hi Akina. Thank you. It worked for me but can you please help me how this query is working?

Comment: @user14788075 Some explanations added.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL | WITH clause
Last Updated: 05-09-2019
The SQL WITH clause was introduced by Oracle in the Oracle 9i release 2 database. The SQL WITH clause allows you to give a sub-query block a name (a process also called sub-query refactoring), which can be referenced in several places within the main SQL query.

The clause is used for defining a temporary relation such that the output of this temporary relation is available and is used by the query that is associated with the WITH clause.
Queries that have an associated WITH clause can also be written using nested sub-queries but doing so add more complexity to read/debug the SQL query.
WITH clause is not supported by all database system.
The name assigned to the sub-query is treated as though it was an inline view or table
The SQL WITH clause was introduced by Oracle in the Oracle 9i release 2 database.
Syntax:

WITH temporaryTable (averageValue) as
    (SELECT avg(Attr1)
    FROM Table),
    SELECT Attr1
    FROM Table
    WHERE Table.Attr1 > temporaryTable.averageValue;


In this query, WITH clause is used to define a temporary relation temporaryTable that has only 1 attribute average value. averageValue holds the average value of column Attr1 described in relation Table. The SELECT statement that follows the WITH clause will produce only those tuples where the value of Attr1 in relation Table is greater than the average value obtained from the WITH clause statement.

Note: When a query with a WITH clause is executed, first the query mentioned within the  clause is evaluated and the output of this evaluation is stored in a temporary relation. Following this, the main query associated with the WITH clause is finally executed that would use the temporary relation produced.



Queries

Example 1:  Find all the employee whose salary is more than the average salary of all employees.
Name of the relation: Employee

EMPLOYEEID  NAME    SALARY
100011  Smith       50000
100022  Bill        94000
100027  Sam         70550
100845  Walden      80000
115585  Erik        60000
1100070 Kate        69000

SQL Query:

WITH temporaryTable(averageValue) as
    (SELECT avg(Salary)
    from Employee), 
        SELECT EmployeeID,Name, Salary 
        FROM Employee, temporaryTable 
        WHERE Employee.Salary > temporaryTable.averageValue;
Output:

EMPLOYEEID  NAME    SALARY
100022  Bill        94000
100845  Walden      80000
Explanation: The average salary of all employees is 70591. Therefore, all employees whose salary is more than the obtained average lies in the output relation.
```

Comment: I tried the above scenario earlier but WITH clause is not supported as I am working on as400 system.